# French accented text replaced with ? in woocommerce product list

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, encoding

I am building a website for a french company which sells products using Woocommerce and Elementor Pro.

Almost all of the website is in french and I face no issues there.

Only when I upload the csv file of the product list with the name and description of the products, the accented french characters such as á, à, â, é, è, ê, í, ì, î, ó, ò, ô, ú, ù, û. etc get replaced by ?.

The characters all seem fine in the csv file.

I have changed the charset to utf8 in the wp-config file.

The database has utf8 encoding.

I have changed the blog_charset to utf8.

Installed the utf8-sanitize plugin.

But still the problem persists.

Following is the link to the page where the normal text has no issues but the product names have question marks in them.
http://startyourdaywith.com/bsante/food/

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried changing the accents themselves in the CSV? For example, instead of including `é` replace it with its HTML escaped equivalent - `&eacute;`?

Comment: That is working but I will have to do it for every character that is showing the ? sign. Was looking for a faster way to do this. Directly copying from the csv file into the product page was also working but there are many products I can't fill  each one separately.

Comment: You should be able to create a PHP script that parses the CSV file, replaces all the accents with their HTML-escaped characters (I think WP has a function for that), and *then* import that CSV. It's two steps instead of one, but will ensure not only proper import but also better cross-browser compatibility.